# How to Change Time of Date/Time Field

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, datetime

When I am trying to save the Date/Time Field of an Object,the time should saved by round off to some fixed time e.g. when I am selecting date as 2/26/2014 the time automatically comes as the present time i.e 10:46 AM. But I want to save it as 11:00 AM after clicking the save button in database, that is when the time is between   10:30 AM to 11:00 AM it should get saved as 11:00 AM. Also if time is between 10:00 AM to 10:30 AM then it get saved as 10:30 AM in database.
How should in proceed.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need simple trigger to do this job (before insert and update), let trigger call this method

Trigger

```
trigger SomeTrigger on SomeObject (Before Insert, Before Update) {
    SomeClass.setTime(trigger.new);
}
```

Class

```
Class SomeClass{
    public static void setTime(SomeObject[] sos){
        for(SomeObject so : sos){
           if(so.Date_Time_Field__c == null ){
               continue;     
           }
           if(so.Date_Time_Field__c.minute() > 30 ){
               so.Date_Time_Field__c = so.Date_Time_Field__c.addMinutes(60 - so.Date_Time_Field__c.minute()).addSeconds(-1 * so.Date_Time_Field__c.second() )   
           }
           else{
                so.Date_Time_Field__c = so.Date_Time_Field__c.addMinutes(30 - so.Date_Time_Field__c.minute()).addSeconds(-1 * so.Date_Time_Field__c.second() )  
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey birthus..thanks for the code ! Its working fine...